# PersistentObjectException: Uninitialized proxy passed to persist

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working with Spring Data JPA and an MySQL database for a records management system. Below are two entities that I have modeled and I am trying to persist a Policy record to the database:

**Policy Entity:**

```
public class Policy {

    private String policyNumber;
    private String policyName;
    private Steward steward;
    private PolicyHolder policyHolder;

    @Id
    @Column(length = 30)
    public String getPolicyNumber() {
        return policyNumber;
    }

    public void setPolicyNumber(String policyNumber) {
        this.policyNumber = policyNumber;
    }

    @Column(length = 80)
    public String getPolicyName() {
        return policyName;
    }

    public void setPolicyName(String policyName) {
        this.policyName = policyName;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "policy", orphanRemoval = true, optional = false)
    public PolicyHolder getPolicyHolder() {
        return policyHolder;
    }
}
```

**PolicyHolder Entity:**

```
@Entity
public class PolicyHolder extends PolicyMember {

    private Policy policy;

    public PolicyHolder() {
        super();
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "policy_policyNumber", referencedColumnName = "policyNumber")
    public Policy getPolicy() {
        return policy;
    }

    public void setPolicy(Policy policy) {
        this.policy = policy;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PolicyHolder{" +
                "policy=" + policy +
                "} " + super.toString();
    }
}
```

PolicyMember Entity:

```
@Entity
public abstract class PolicyMember {

    private CompositePolicyMemberPK policyMemberId;
    private String firstname;
    private String surname;
    private LocalDate dateOfDeath;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    private MemberStatus status;
    private BillingStatus billingStatus;
    private String nationalId;
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
    private Gender gender;
    private String msisdn;
    private LocalDate closureDate;
    private String createdBy;
    private String memberType;


    private PackageBenefit packageBenefit;

    private List<DependantTransferRequest> transferRequests;

    @EmbeddedId
    public CompositePolicyMemberPK getPolicyMemberId() {
        return policyMemberId;
    }

    public void setPolicyMemberId(CompositePolicyMemberPK policyMemberId) {
        this.policyMemberId = policyMemberId;
    }

    @Column(length = 50)
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    @Column(length = 50)
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }


    @Convert(converter = MemberStatusConverter.class)
    public MemberStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(MemberStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Convert(converter = BillingStatusConverter.class)
    public BillingStatus getBillingStatus() {
        return billingStatus;
    }

    public void setBillingStatus(BillingStatus billingStatus) {
        this.billingStatus = billingStatus;
    }

    @Column(length = 20)
    public String getNationalId() {
        return nationalId;
    }

    public void setNationalId(String nationalId) {
        this.nationalId = nationalId;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Column(length = 15)
    public String getMsisdn() {
        return msisdn;
    }

    public void setMsisdn(String msisdn) {
        this.msisdn = msisdn;
    }

    @Column(length = 50)
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    @Column(name = "memberType", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public String getMemberType() {
        return memberType;
    }

    public void setMemberType(String memberType) {
        this.memberType = memberType;
    }


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "policyMember", optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public PackageBenefit getPackageBenefit() {
        return packageBenefit;
    }

    public void setPackageBenefit(PackageBenefit packageBenefit) {
        this.packageBenefit = packageBenefit;
    }

    public LocalDate getDateOfDeath() {
        return dateOfDeath;
    }

    public void setDateOfDeath(LocalDate dateOfDeath) {
        this.dateOfDeath = dateOfDeath;
    }

    public LocalDate getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public LocalDate getClosureDate() {
        return closureDate;
    }

    public void setClosureDate(LocalDate closureDate) {
        this.closureDate = closureDate;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(LocalDateTime creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "dependantToTransfer")
    public List<DependantTransferRequest> getTransferRequests() {
        return transferRequests;
    }

    public void setTransferRequests(List<DependantTransferRequest> transferRequests) {
        this.transferRequests = transferRequests;
    }
}
```

Composite Key:

```
@Embeddable
public class CompositePolicyMemberPK implements Serializable {

    private String policyNumber;

    private String suffixNumber;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CompositePolicyMemberPK(String policyNumber, String suffixNumber) {
        super();
        this.policyNumber = policyNumber;
        this.suffixNumber = suffixNumber;
    }

    public CompositePolicyMemberPK() {
        super();
    }

    @Column(length = 30)
    public String getPolicyNumber() {
        return this.policyNumber;
    }

    public void setPolicyNumber(String policyNumber) {
        this.policyNumber = policyNumber;
    }

    @Column(length = 2)
    public String getSuffixNumber() {
        return this.suffixNumber;
    }

    public void setSuffixNumber(String suffixNumber) {
        this.suffixNumber = suffixNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof CompositePolicyMemberPK)) {
            return false;
        }
        CompositePolicyMemberPK other = (CompositePolicyMemberPK) o;
        return (getPolicyNumber() == null ? other.getPolicyNumber() == null : getPolicyNumber().equals(other.getPolicyNumber())) && (getSuffixNumber() == null ? other.getSuffixNumber() == null : getSuffixNumber().equals(other.getSuffixNumber()));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (getPolicyNumber() == null ? 0 : getPolicyNumber().hashCode());
        result = prime * result + (getSuffixNumber() == null ? 0 : getSuffixNumber().hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getPolicyNumber() + "-" + this.getSuffixNumber();
    }
}
```

**The code that is responsible for persisiting the policy is as follows:**

```
public Subscriber addMemberToSteward(Long stewardId, Subscriber subscriber) {

    Steward steward = this.findStewardById(stewardId);

    if(steward == null){
        throw new EcosureException(String.format("No steward found with id '%s'.",stewardId));
    }


    final BillingStatus billingStatus = BillingStatus.REG_IN_PROGRESS;
    final MemberStatus memberStatus = MemberStatus.NEW;
    final ProductPackage product = productService.findPackageById(subscriber.getProductPackageId());

    subscriber.setNationalId(nationalIDNumberUtils.formatIdNumber(subscriber.getNationalId()));

    final PolicyHolder policyHolder = convertToPolicyHolder(subscriber, product, billingStatus, memberStatus);
    Policy policy = getPolicyFromSubscriberInfo(subscriber, policyHolder);
    policy.setSteward(steward);
    policy.setStatus(PolicyStatus.NEW);
    System.out.println("Policy Holder" + policyHolder);

    policyRepository.save(policy);
    return subscriber;
}
```

**The getPolicyFromSubscriberInfo method is below:**

private Policy getPolicyFromSubscriberInfo(final Subscriber subscriberInfo, final PolicyHolder policyHolder) throws {

```
    final Policy policy = new Policy();

    policy.setMsisdn(subscriberInfo.getMsisdn());
    policy.setPolicyNumber(policyNumberGenerator.getNextPolicyNumber());

    policy.setPolicyName(policyHolder.getFirstname() + " " + policyHolder.getSurname());
    policyHolder.setPolicy(policy);
    CompositePolicyMemberPK policyMemberId = new CompositePolicyMemberPK();
    policyMemberId.setPolicyNumber(policy.getPolicyNumber());

    policyMemberId.setSuffixNumber(policyNumberGenerator.getNextSuffix(policy.getPolicyNumber(),true));

    policyHolder.setPolicyMemberId(policyMemberId);
    policy.setPolicyHolder(policyHolder);

    return policy;
}
```

The PolicyRepository is shown below:

```
public interface PolicyRepository extends JpaRepository<Policy, String> {

}
```

When I try to persist a Policy entity I am getting the error below:

```
2016-12-09 09:47:43,461 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-15) UT005023: Exception handling request to /ecosure-api/api/v3/stewards/243/policies: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist(); nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at com.econetwireless.ecosure.api.filters.AuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationTokenFilter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist(); nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:418)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:492)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1272.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.econetwireless.ecosure.service.stewards.StewardServiceImpl.addMemberToSteward(StewardServiceImpl.java:115)
    at com.econetwireless.ecosure.api.controllers.StewardController.addMemberToGroup(StewardController.java:91)
    at com.econetwireless.ecosure.api.controllers.StewardController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$69e389b2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.econetwireless.ecosure.api.controllers.StewardController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2d501d51.addMemberToGroup(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1267.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:506)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:768)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:761)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:391)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:778)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:751)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:756)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146)
```

Can anyone please assist me in identifying where I am going wrong.

Comment: What is the code of `getPolicyFromSubscriberInfo()`?

Comment: Hi Nikos, i have edited the post to include getPolicyFromSubscriberInfo().